Issue with Audio 24.04
For some reason I cannot play music or any audio over my laptop speakers, but if I plug in any other speaker or blue tooth speaker it works fine. I saw somewhere that I needed to uninstall and reinstall my audio drivers, so I did so pipewire, alsa, and pulseaudio but this didn't work.
I saw somewhere else where a patchwork fix was to downgrade the kernel to 6.5, but I'm semi new to the linux eco system so I am a little hesitant on doing that.
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 6.8.0.45 generic.
    lsof /dev/snd/*
COMMAND    PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
pipewire  3643 razer   48u   CHR 116,18      0t0 1109 /dev/snd/controlC1
pipewire  3643 razer   59u   CHR  116,1      0t0  533 /dev/snd/seq
pipewire  3643 razer   60u   CHR  116,1      0t0  533 /dev/snd/seq
wireplumb 3647 razer   35u   CHR 116,18      0t0 1109 /dev/snd/controlC1
wireplumb 3647 razer   37u   CHR 116,18      0t0 1109 /dev/snd/controlC1
wireplumb 3647 razer   38u   CHR 116,18      0t0 1109 /dev/snd/controlC1
wireplumb 3647 razer   41u   CHR  116,7      0t0 1020 /dev/snd/controlC0

alsamixer

I just fixed mine, but if anyone has this issue in the future all you need to do is go to https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207423#c94 and make sure you have alsa-tools installed before you run the script
Turned out to be Razer laptop issue.
